# is there an opportunity for me to reduce main.js file size in order to improve web performance?

Tags: angular, performance, web

Context: so i'm trying to optimize the web performance of an angular 16 application as per pagespeed.dev. The major suggestions were to decrease unused javascript files and unused css which were render blocking

[networks tab shows huge styles.css and main.js file size]
[image]

[the build file sizes]
[image]

[source map explorer shows a huge bundle size consisting of many modules]
[image]

We already have lazy loading as per

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'items',
    loadChildren: () => import('./items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsModule)
  }
];
```

and standalone components
and the 1mb main.js and 800kb styes.scss is after brotli compression
so was wondering if there is anything i could do to further reduce the size of main.js. Thank you!

Comment: you can lazy load many things, not just routed pages. for example pdf-viewer piece can be downloaded only when user clicks on "preview" button `async onClick() {const pdf = await import('pdf-viewer')}`

Comment: a lot of the size of an angular app will depend on configuration.  things like source maps help development, but you will want to disable in production.

https://angular.io/cli/build
here area the available configuration options you can enable or disable which will help reduce bundle size

Answer (score 0):

They are many strategies to improve your Angular App performance and reduce the main.js bundle. You should start with code splitting and lazy loading.

1. Reduce the usage of 3rd party libraries in app.module - this is the MAIN reason why your application has a huge main.js bundle.

You can also try:

2. Avoid using Angular Material - this library is super heavy and will increase you bundle big time. You won't believe how your performance will improve after you uninstall it.
3. Upgrade to Angular 17 to use @defer loading to lazy load standalone components. When used with @defer() {  } standalone components with included libraries that are for example 150kb, will no be included in the main bundle and you will be able to see them as a separate lazy loaded chunk when you run ng build command.
4. Use onPush change detection when possible. This will ensure that the components are rendered only once, not multiple times and will minimize main thread work.